# How do i check if image in PictureBox is changed ? And add that image in a datagridview

Tags: datagridview, picturebox

Im trying to add image img to dtgv but it gives me an error "this image does not exist in the courent context"

```
dgv private double ShtoNeGrid(string Targa, string Ora, double Pagesa,Image img) 
{ img = pictureBox2.Image; double result = 0; 
Targa = KlientTxt.Text.ToString();
 Ora = OraLbl.Text; 
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Targa, Ora, Pagesa); 
return result; 
}
```

But when i call it,it tells me that the name "img" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: So i got this Add in dgv
private double ShtoNeGrid(string Targa, string Ora, double Pagesa,Image img)
        {

             img = pictureBox2.Image;
           


            double result = 0;
            Targa = KlientTxt.Text.ToString();
            Ora = OraLbl.Text;
          
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Targa, Ora, Pagesa);

            return result;
        }
But when i call it,it tells me that the name "img" does not exist in the current context..

Comment: Sorry bcs im new here,i didnt knew where to post the code :/